# Time complexity of algorithm with multiple recursion

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

i'm trying to known time complexity about the following algorithms :

```
static int g(int[] a) {
  return g(a, 0, a.length-1);
}

static int g(int[] a, int i, int j) {
  if(i == j) return a[i];
  int onefourth = (j+1-i)/4;
  return g(a, i, i+onefourth) + g(a, i+onefourth+1, j);
}
```

This is my attempt :

The algorithm g(int[] a, int i, int j) split the dimension of array a by 4, and call recursively itself via multiple recursion. I can write the following recurrencies equation T(n) = T(n/4) + T(3n/4) + c = .... = T(n/4^k) + T(3n/4^k) + kc. Here, i have problem to choose a value of k. Anyone can help me ?

Comment: `T(n/4) + T(3n/4) + c = .... = T(n/4^k) + T(3n/4^k) + kc` - this is incorrect, try to think of why.

Comment: T(n) = T(n/4) + T(3n/4) + c is just the equation, higher powers will appear if you substitute n for n/4, that is why it is a recurrence equation in the first place. Now to me, it appears that if you could solve it using substitution ( T(n) = O(nlogn)) you could prove that it is O(nlogn).

Comment: @SomeDude substituting basically any function would satisfy the equation - O(n), O(n^2), O(sqrt(n)) etc all work.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Not every function. You should prove that there exists values that satisfy T(n) <= O(nlogn) I suspect you can prove there exists values for every function.

Comment: Is substitution the only method you can use? If not then you can try the [Akra-Bazzi method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method).

Comment: [Master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)) definitely provides right answer for divide and conquer relations, substitution is kind of quick and dirty way.

Comment: @SomeDude I'm not sure that the Master theorem can *directly* give an answer for a branched recurrence like this; the only way would be to substitute one of the terms with the other (`T(n/4)` with `T(3n/4)` and vice versa) and compute the upper/lower bounds with MT.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Is an error to consider T(3n/4) ≈ 3*T(n/4) ?

Comment: @SomeDude Are you aware that the correct answer is `O(n)`, and not `O(n log(n))`?

Comment: @btilly not sure how it is O(n) please provide some explanation that would be great and probably will be the answe that user is looking for.

Comment: Why should `T(3n/4) ≈ 3*T(n/4)`? Can you justify this assumption? Sorry if I sound confrontational - but you cannot assume things without at least an idea of how to prove them.

Comment: @SomeDude the Akra-Bazzi method confirms this. On the contrary - can you prove *your* answer O(n log n)?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog It's only an attempt, because i misunderstand how to solve recurrencies equation of algorithm with multiple recursion of different input size.

Comment: @btilly I said "it appears to me..." I wasn't sure either if it is O(nlogn). Will check the answer posted here. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what techniques you were taught, but I know how I would figure this out from scratch.

When you divide the problem, apportion the cost of the recursive calls to the lower level proportionately to their sizes.  Then ask the question of what the largest value is that could be apportioned to any value on the bottom.

Here is what I mean.

If you're looking at a range of length `1` you'll have some constant cost `c`.

If you're looking at a range of length `2` you'll have a constant recursion cost `r` divided evenly for a cost per element of `c+r/2`.

If you're looking at a range of length `3` the first element will get a cost of `c + r/3` but the latter pair first gets `2/3 r` at the top level, which is then split in 2 with another recursion cost for a total cost of `c + r/2 + r/3`.

And so on.

Now here is the challenge.  What is the largest recursive cost that can be attributed to a particular call?  Worst case somewhere in the chain is `r` for its level, plus `3/4 r` for the level above it, plus `(3/4)^2 r` for the level above that, and so on.  Can you find an upper bound?

Can you turn that upper bound into an upper bound on the cost attributed to a single element at the bottom?

Multiply that bound by the number of elements and you'll have your `O(n)`.

Comment: Thanks you very much. In few words you have consider only the most expensive recursive call for each level, in that case g(a, i+onefourth+1, j).